# Javascript: loops output in div

Tags: javascript, html, loops

So i have done some school assignments, and suddenly i just got stuck on this one.  This is my script: (its working, but it doesnt show up the way i want to).

```
function multiplikasjon(){

 var myVar = "i++";
 var minlokke = "";
 for (i=0; i<=100; i++) {
   minlokke += i+ " x " + i+ " = " +(i*i)+ "<br>";
 }
 document.write(minlokke)}
```

and this is in the body-tag

```
<a href="javascript:multiplikasjon()">click me</a>
```

Its working as i want, but i want it to show up when I click a button. I have tried different solutions with a button, but i can't get any output under the button. (Not open a new window, like its doing now).

Thank you for answering!

Comment: What is the point of the string you assign to `myVar`?

Comment: Where is `generateTable()` ?

Comment: i solved it! thanks to wye

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` works only when the page is loaded.
To write something when the page is already there, use the following.

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"> I want the var minlokke here </div>;
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML + minlokke
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is execute JavaScript on the click of a button, not just a link?

To do that, use the `onclick` attribute:

```
<button onclick="multiplikasjon()">click me</button>

<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="multiplikasjon()" />
```

You can also assign those properties in JavaScript directly:

```
myElement.onclick = function() {
    doStuff();
};
```

In fact, even links should probably be using `onclick` instead of linking to `javascript` URLs like you're doing.

Comment: i know it was a bad solution, but it was the only solution i could know if my script was correct. thanks for answering ! :)